# ios issue with log calculation

Tags: objective-c

I am working on a calculation for free space loss and hitting a snag.

Doing this calculation:

```
fslLoss = 36.6 + (20 * log(fromAntenna/5280)) + (20 * log(serviceFreq))
```

Where fslLoss is a float and fromAntenna and servicefreq are integers:

```
NSLog(@"the freespace Loss is %0.01f", fslLoss);
```

The result is "the freespace Loss is -inf"

The issue appears to be in the 20log(fromAntenna/5280) section, as I get normal results without it.

BTW ... tried log10 with the same results.

Thanks for the help,

padapa

Comment: It would be ever so slightly more efficient to do: `fslLoss = 36.6 + 20 * (log(fromAntenna / 5280.0) + log(serviceFreq));`. This eliminates one multiplication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say `fromAntenna` is an integer, so `fromAntenna/5280` will be calculated with integer arithmetic. That means it will be rounded (floored, technically), probably not what you intended.

Fix it with:

```
log( (double) fromAntenna / 5280.0 )
```

Comment: `serviceFreq` doesn't have the same problem because it is automatically promoted when calling the function; there is no `log` function defined for `int`s.

Comment: `log(fromAntenna / 5280.0)` will already do the trick because the compiler automatically promotes `fromAntenna` to a double in that case. No explicit cast required.

Comment: true, but personally I prefer to make everything explicit. Another thing worth noting is that if `float` precision should be used instead of `double`, it should be `5280.0f`.

Comment: [insert debate about superfluous casts here]. But you are right, it works both ways. Just wanted to mention that the cast isn't necessary. Also, when single precision is enough, you should use `logf()` instead of `log()`.

Comment: Dave, thanks for the helping me understand what was happening ... I was where JustSid was,thinking the compiler would automatically cast the var if needed ... it just didn't do it.  Explicitly setting it made it work correctly.

Comment: @padapa Let's be clear on this. A compiler never automatically casts anything. The term you want is "promotes". In the case of `log(intValue1 / intValue2)` what happens first is the division. Since both sides are integer, the result is integer. The integer result of the division is then promoted to a double because that is what the `log` function takes. Since your `intValue2` was larger, the result of the integer division was 0. In the case of `log(intValue3)`, the integer value is promoted to `double` and you get the expected result. Continued on next comment ...

Comment: @padapa In the case of `log(intValue / doubleValue)`, the division is done first. Since the two sides are different, the integer value is automatically promoted to a double and then the division is done giving a double result type. No further promotion of this is required since `log` takes a double.

Answer (score 4):

`log(0)` is -inf. The integer division inside the logarithm may be zero. Use `fromAntenna/5280.0` to get float division.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is correctly using fromAntenna & serviceFreq as ints and that's not giving you good results when fslLoss is a float.  Use some float casts and you'll have better luck:

```
 fslLoss = 36.6 + (20 * log((float)fromAntenna/5280)) + (20 * log((float)serviceFreq));
```

Comment: Mike, Thanks for the help. While you are right, I only need 1 or 2 digits precise for this application.